# At what position in the circuit is the origin of the graph of the voltage in the circuit as function of the position located?

Tags: circuit-analysis

The circuit in the top picture above shows a battery with internal resistance r=1Ω and two external resistors with resistance R1=2Ω and R2=3Ω. The bottom picture shows the voltage in the circuit as function of the position. The x-axis is not fully on scale.At what position in the circuit is the origin of the right picture located?

My answer would be that it is position a because the first decrease in slope is less steeper than the second decrease which means that the first external resistor acting has a smaller value than the second resistor acting. I am not sure when it comes to the increase of voltage which happens when the position is in the battery because it charges it again. What I am wondering is whether the batterys internal resistance also consumes volatage, that would correspond to the third (the smallest) decrease in volage from the graph. can charge it above the origin value. If that is the case the oriin would be at a, but I am not sure what the internal resistance r does[image]

Comment: What reference node did you pick for your guess?

Comment: I think the origin is at a or the graph is incorrect because I dont know about the last third of the graph

Comment: @Andyaka I think it is a, or the graph is incorrect so none of them, because I am not sure about the last third of the graph

Comment: How does the x axis of the graph relate the closed loop of the circuit? Are you traversing clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I did it anticlockwise, from r to R1 to R2 and so on

Comment: Why don't you calculate the voltages across all of the resistors, carefully marking the polarity of each voltage. That should help you.